# Chrome theme - rotate images dynamically

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to develop a chrome theme. I see the [documentations](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/themes) and they will only explain what kind of information to put inside the `manifest.json` file. I would ask if is possible to change the images of the theme every x amount of time with javascript.

Comment: No, themes can't run js.

Comment: Ok. I can install the unsigned theme like extension right? I'm trying and the chrome aspect will not change ?